# CiviMember Sync Not Recording Membership Payments

Tags: civimember

We have a site for members where when they sign up they go to a membership drupal role. This is a paid site for membership. So all works well with the member signing up and getting the invoice etc. It even gets added to the Membership role in drupal which is great. However, when we visit the individual civi record there is a transation for a payment but not actual membership recording. The membership is in the right financial type and I have doubled checked the details. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you specify a little bit more? Is the membership not showing in the membership tab? Or is it not created at all?

Comment: Hi Fabian. The Membership is not showing in the Membership tab of the one user and in the Membership section. For another user who purchase an hour before it shows in both section. I have tried to recreate the issue but cannot seem to recreate it. I noticed that we have an automated login process after purchase which may be causing the issue.